# Proposed proof for quasi-metric result

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces

A *quasi-metric* on a set $X$ is mapping $\rho: X \times X \rightarrow [0, \infty)$ satisfying the following conditions:

- $\rho(x,y) \geq 0~~\text{and}~~\rho(x,x) = 0;$
- $\rho(x,z) \leq \rho(x,y) + \rho(y,z)~~~\text{for all }x,y,z \in X$;
- $\rho(x,y) = \rho(y,x)=0 \implies x=y~~~\text{for all }x,y\in X$.

Note that $\rho(x,y)$ is not necessary equivalent to $\rho(y,x)$ with these assumptions.

We are further given the **property** that:
$$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\rho(x,x_{n})=0~~~\text{and}~~~\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\rho(y,x_{n})=0 \implies x=y$$

**Problem:**
Show that $(X, \tau_{\rho})$ is Hausdorff.

**Proposed Proof:**
Take $x,y \in X$ such that $x \neq y$. Consider the sequences $\{x_{n}\}_{n} \subset X$ and $\{y_{m}\}_{m} \subset X$ taken such that $x_{n} \in B_{\rho}\big(x,\frac{1}{n}\big)$ and $y_{m} \in B_{\rho}\big(y, \frac{1}{m}\big)$ for $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$. It follows that $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\rho(x,x_{n}) = 0$ and $\lim\limits_{m \rightarrow \infty}\rho(y,y_{m}) = 0$. It follows from the property that $\rho(y,x_{n}) \not\to 0$. Hence there exists some $\epsilon > 0$ such that for no $N$ does $n \geq N$ imply that $x_{n} \in B(y,\epsilon)$. It follows that $x \notin B_{\rho}(y,\epsilon)$. We can apply the same reasoning to find an open ball $B_{\rho}(x,\epsilon_{1})$ such that $y \notin B_{\rho}(x, \epsilon_{1})$. By taking $\epsilon$ and $\epsilon_{1}$ sufficiently small we can obtain disjoint open balls containing $x$ and $y$ respectively. We can do this by taking some $x_{k} \in B_{\rho}(x, \epsilon_{1})$, where $x_{k} \notin B_{\rho}(y,\epsilon)$ and then considering $\epsilon_{2} := \rho(x,x_{k})$. Then we have disjoint open balls $B_{\rho}(x,\epsilon_{2})$ and $B_{\rho}(y,\epsilon)$ containing $x$ and $y$ respectively.

$\square$

**Question:** 
Can anyone see how to show that the last open balls are in fact disjoint? Is this proof okay?

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Suppose that for all $\alpha>0:B_{\rho}\left(  x,\alpha\right)  \cap B_{\rho
}\left(  y,\alpha\right)  \neq0$. Hence there exists a sequence $z_{n}\in
B_{\rho}\left(  x,\frac{1}{n}\right)  \cap B_{\rho}\left(  y,\frac{1}{n}\right)  $ i.e. $\rho\left(  x,z_{n}\right)  \rightarrow0$ and $\rho\left(
y,z_{n}\right)  \rightarrow0$ hence $x=y$

Comment: @user72012 Nice answer. Much simpler.